# Error when calling intent in setOnItemClickListener RecyclerView

Tags: java, android

Im trying to intent Upcoming.java to MeetingDetails.java. I already try toast inside OnItemClickListener and it works, but when i try to intent there is an error.

Upcoming.Java

```
mAdapter = new MeetingsAdapter(meetingList);
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new MeetingDivider(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    MeetingListClickSupport.addTo(recyclerView).setOnItemClickListener(new MeetingListClickSupport.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClicked(RecyclerView recyclerView, int position, View v) {
            Meeting meeting = meetingList.get(position);
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext() , MeetingDetails.class);
            i.putExtra("id", meeting.getId());
            i.putExtra("status", "U");
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

MeetingListClickSupport.java

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mOnItemClickListener != null) {
            RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder = mRecyclerView.getChildViewHolder(v);
            mOnItemClickListener.onItemClicked(mRecyclerView, holder.getAdapterPosition(), v);
        }
     }
```

MeetingsAdapter.java

```
private List<Meeting> meetingsList;

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView mName, description;

    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        mName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mName);
        description = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.description);
    }
}

public MeetingsAdapter(List<Meeting> meetingsList) {
    this.meetingsList = meetingsList;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.activity_meeting_list, parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Meeting meeting = meetingsList.get(position);
    holder.mName.setText(meeting.getName());
    holder.description.setText(meeting.getDescription());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return meetingsList.size();
}
```

I got an error like this :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.erice.attendancecontroller, PID: 1358
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread android.app.ActivityThread.getApplicationThread()' on a null object reference
                  at com.example.erice.attendancecontroller.Upcoming$1.onItemClicked(Upcoming.java:65)
                  at com.example.erice.attendancecontroller.MeetingListClickSupport$1.onClick(MeetingListClickSupport.java:20)
```

Please if anyone can help me, thank you very much

Comment: It would be better if you start by telling us what you're trying to do so that we understand the context without reading every bit of code. Down voting because it's not clear, even though there's valid answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Hey pass the current Activity context not the Application context.

Comment: im trying to pass Upcoming.this but still got the same error

Comment: @RiczTan just use `this` Instead of `Upcoming.this`.

Comment: @Ironman when i use this, there will be a red line cannot resolve constructor MeetingListClickSupport.OnitemClickListener

Comment: Check your parameters for call `mOnItemClickListener.onItemClicked`. I think one of them is `null`

Comment: @RiczTan I have update my answer with full explanation just check it out

Comment: Test by moving the code from the onClickListener to the onCreate function. Does it crash there?

Comment: @lionscribe, yeah it crashes outside onCreate

Answer (score 0):

In your this line

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
```

your passing `getApplicationContext()` you have to pass `Activity` `context`.

use this

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
```

then in `RecycleView.Adapter` class Create Constructor.

```
public MeetingsAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter
{
    Activity context;

     public MeetingsAdapter(Activity context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }
}
```

Now in your `OnClick` use this way

```
Intent i = new Intent(context , MeetingDetails.class);
```

Comment: thank you for your response, but when i use context in OnClick where context refers to ? since i have MeetingsAdapter.Java and i already create a constructor public MeetingsAdapter(Activity context) and declare Activity context in MeetingsAdapter.java

Comment: I add my MeetingsAdapter.java in the post